# Html Widget src appears and then disappears on refresh

Tags: html, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

My HTML Script tag has a src, but then the div id to display the widget appears and then disappears on refresh. The DIV is still there but its not bringing in the source.
I don't know why as I get no error message in the Javascript debugger.
One weird thing is it doesn't disappear in Localhost but ONLY in Azure.

Refresh the page to re-produce the issue.
I'm using Blazor .NET Core, and the widget is at:

Site:
https://markstest1.azurewebsites.net/

Source file:
https://www.climatelevels.org/graphs/js/co2.php?theme=dark-unica&pid=2degreesinstitute

Source Code
Startup.cs (CORS added for site). One site is http.
Could that be an issue?

```
public class Startup
    {
        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(//name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("https://www.climatelevels.org", "http://www.2degreesinstitute.org")
                                                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                                                  .AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
            });
```

DIV Tag with id to source file. Razor file.

```
<div id="co2-widget-container"></div>
```

_Host.cshtml file with  tags

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.climatelevels.org/graphs/js/co2.php?theme=dark-unica&pid=2degreesinstitute"></script></script>
```

Comment: It could be a mixed content issue. Since Firefox allows Mixed content (https, http) in Localhost, that's probably why I am getting it to work there. Still researching.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be loading now correctly. The answer was that Blazor was starting too early and canceling the javascript  loads in the _Host file. It seems I had to add the tag

`<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>`
to the Blazor script file so it doesn't start too quickly and let's the startup file initiate Blazor instead. Then mutate the src URL into a Blazor.start() call after DOMContentLoaded is loaded.

```
<script>document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        Blazor.start().then(function () {
        var customScript = document.createElement('script');
        customScript.setAttribute('src', '//www.website...');
        document.head.appendChild(customScript);
            });
        });</script>
```

Resource link used:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22643
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-5.0